# 'as he had lived'

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, conjunctions, clauses

In the clause 'He died as he had lived', what is the grammatical function of 'as he had lived'? I know it modifies 'died', and I know 'as' can be used.

Comment: In this sentence, "as" is not a preposition. It is actually a conjunction.

Comment: Thank you. What is the easiest way to tell the difference?

Comment: If 'as' is used to compare using a direct object ( "light as a feather" ), it's a preposition. In this sentence, as is used to connect two parts of the sentence ( He died AS he had lived)

Comment: "As" is a preposition, so "as he had lived" is a preposition phrase functioning as complement of "died". The comparative clause "he had lived" is complement of the preposition "as".

Comment: @BillJ Not an adjunct/modifier of the VP?

Comment: @MetaEd That's a very 19th century conception of prepositions, although you will still find it used in dictionaries (which nearly all have a 19th century-level understanding of grammar) and in some schools. However, 21st century grammars such as *Oxford Modern English Grammar* for example, prepositions are a word class just like nouns verbs adjectives and so forth, and just like verbs can take different types of complement, for example noun phrases or clauses. And under that modern simpler and more elegant classification *as* is a preposition here, not one of the small number of subordinators.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> He died [as he had lived].

As the Original Poster suspects, the string *as he had lived* is a Modifier of the verb phrase *died*. (It's a verb phrase as opposed to merely a verb because it forms the predicate of the clause). Modifiers of verb phrases or clauses are often referred to as 'Adjuncts' (or 'Adverbials').

The string *as he had lived* is a preposition phrase, where we see the word *as* heading an equative construction. In old-fashioned grammars, the word *as* would be considered a subordinating conjunction. In modern grammars it is considered a preposition regardless of whether it is followed by a noun phrase or a clause.

Comment: A learner might want to know how we can know that "he had lived" is an "equative" construction when all we know is that "as" is a preposition. Is there an online resource, perhaps, that groups clause-complemented-prepositions according to the types of complement-clauses they license, or that defines the preposition's semantic functions?

Comment: @TimR There might be, but I'm not familiar with it. There's hardly any  that take comparative clauses though (*as/like/than* perhaps a couple of others). This is something you'd need to deal when learning about equatives/comparatives.

Comment: It's all been very useful to me. Thank you.